# Чи можливо сьогодні перезапозичити слово іншомовного походження?

Tags: запозичені-слова

Дізнався було я про існування аналога якогось слова в українській мові, чиє звучання дуже сподобалося. (Наприклад, слово *avenida* у іспанській та португальській мовах - у ньому багато голосних і воно могло б замінити слово *проспект*, що прийшло до нас з латинської ЧЕРЕЗ російську).

Звичайно, якщо б я був відомим письменником чи поетом, то почав би використовувати це слово у своїх творах і з часом воно з'явилося б у вжитку в українській мові, згодом його б додали у словники.

Але маємо те, що маємо. Чи відомі вам приклади останніх років, коли якесь слово було повністю перезапозичене? Мені згадуються тільки пара *вертоліт*/*гелікоптер*, але цій історії майже тридцять років вже. Спроби замінити радянсько-українське слово *міліціонер* на *міліціянта* з диаспори, які відбувалися приблизно у той же час в середині 1990-х років, чомусь не мали успіху.

Що робити, якщо є сильне бажання перезапозичити якесь слово? Звертатися до відомих письменників, поетів, журналістів з пропозицією використовувати це слово у своїх творах замість сталого? Те ж саме робити з ЛСД (лідерами суспільної думки) у соцмережах, а потім, якщо процес зрушить з місця, почати "обробляти" професійних філологів та видавників словників?

Який має бути алгоритм?

Comment: Не існує зараз в Україні правил введення нових слів в українську мову. Проспе́кт (від лат. prospectus — вид, перспектива). Це не російське слово. Зайдіть у словотвір.

Comment: Також не розумію, нащо одне запозичене слово замінювати іншим. До того ж, чому з іспанської мови? Як ми обираємо, звідки запозичити? Можливо все, справді, якби ви були письменником - могли би зробити.

Comment: Друзі, мені здається, що ми не читаємо текст запитання. Воно полягає не в тому, що міняти слово *проспект* на *авеніда*. Це конкретне слово може бути просто невдалим прикладом. А саме запитання — про можливість повторного запозичення і формальний механізм такого перезапозичення. І я вважаю, що таке запитання має право на існування — ймовірно, за умови редагування з метою зробити його менш opinion-based.

Comment: @Vitaliy Tretyakov, спробуєте відредагувати питання, щоби воно було не так про авеніду й проспект, а радше про саму можливість повторного запозичення?

Comment: Чи можна вважати всю комп'ютерну термінологію "перезапозиченною" (принаймні щоб оновити приклад з гелікоптерами-вертольотами)?

Answer (score 5):

Беріть та користуйтеся. Може, це стане жаргоном вашої групи, а з часом, можливо і нормою.

Думаю, що не треба підтверджувати посиланнями те, що мова розвивається, запозичує нові слова, а жаргонізми кодифікуються і стають нормою. Чи відмирають.

Хтось сказав: "В політиці і граматиці помилка, яку робить більшість, стає істиною". Питання, як зробити слово популярним - це, мабуть, питання маркетингове.